# How to decrease the brightness of a layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how to decrease the brightness of certain layout(I guess they did that)?
Like in this image:
[image]

I tried, setting the android:alpha to 0,6, but it isn't working.
I would appreciate any help.

**EDIT**
This is my layout, i am just testing.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="debugging.transparenttest.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: this is not decreased brightness. this is activity upon another activity with transparent Background

Comment: You are right, thanks.They just call the activity that is over? The initial activity will keep there?

Comment: yes. when You close or finish transparent activity your previous activity will be there

Comment: Thanks man, you solved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not decreased brightness, this is an activity on top of another

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the opacity of the background of your activity like this :

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"                
          android:background="#80000000">
```

80 if half of FF here

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"                
       android:background="#80000000">